# Disable the gestures in PagerAdapter/ViewPager

Tags: android, android-layout, android-viewpager

first of all sorry for my bad english.

I got a working `PagerAdapter` with 3 `Views`. It works fine. I can switch through the Views with normal gestures AND with Buttonclicks. But i want to disable the gestures. Is it possible to switch through the Views only with buttonClicks and disable the gestures?

here is the `PagerAdapter`:

```
public class MyPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {


        public int getCount() {
            return 3;
        }

        public Object instantiateItem(View collection, int position) {

            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) collection.getContext()
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

            int resId = 0;
            switch (position) {
            case 0:
                resId = R.layout.back;
                break;
            case 1:
                resId = R.layout.stock;
                break;
            case 2:
                resId = R.layout.menu;
                break;
            }

            View view = inflater.inflate(resId, null);

            ((ViewPager) collection).addView(view, 0);

            return view;
        }

        @Override
        public void destroyItem(View arg0, int arg1, Object arg2) {
            ((ViewPager) arg0).removeView((View) arg2); 

        }

        @Override
        public boolean isViewFromObject(View arg0, Object arg1) {
            return arg0 == ((View) arg1);

        }

        @Override
        public Parcelable saveState() {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

**SOLVED**:

```
    final View touchView = findViewById(R.id.remotePager);
    touchView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

            return true;
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Override the `onTouchListener()` and return false to disable paging on swipe.

```
public boolean onTouchEvent(android.view.MotionEvent ev) {
        if (super.onTouchEvent(ev)) {
            return false;
        }
}
```

Comment: thanks, solved it this way:

  final View touchView = findViewById(R.id.remotePager);
  touchView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
   @Override
   public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

    return true;
   }
  });